# How to Retrieve all email send definitions by folder (category) ID through the Marketing Cloud API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, c#, send-definition

I'm using the SalesForce Marketing Cloud (Exact Target).

I have a folder ID (category ID) and I want to get all the send definitions (user-initiated sends) in that folder via the SOAP API in C#. I know when retrieving lists, I can create a filter that matches on Category (folder ID).

When I attempt to do the same for email send definitions, I receive the status :

> Error: The Filter Property 'CategoryID' is not a retrievable property.

I tried both Category and CategoryID, and no luck. Anyone have success trying to do this?

Here is my code to set up the filter:

```
        RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest();
        rr.ObjectType = "EmailSendDefinition";
        rr.Properties = new string[] { "ObjectID", "Name", "CategoryID", "SenderProfile.FromName", "SenderProfile.CustomerKey" };

        SimpleFilterPart sfp = new SimpleFilterPart();
        sfp.Property = "CategoryID";
        sfp.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;
        sfp.Value = new string[] { categoryId };
        rr.Filter = sfp;
```

Comment: Was going to reopen your other question but I guess you wanted to get an answer faster. You're right, this is a pretty relevant question, hope you don't mind I updated it a bit to have people discover it easier.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke thanks Sam!  I don't mind at all.  New to using these communities, so learning the conventions on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with CategoryID in SimpleFilter it works, do you have **EmailSendDefinition** as ObjectTye in your request? It is not SendDefinition ObjectType

my raw xml looks like below

```
<ObjectType>EmailSendDefinition</ObjectType><Properties>Name</Properties><Properties>CategoryID</Properties><Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart"><Property>CategoryID</Property><SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator><Value>1234</Value></Filter>
```

set ClientIDs for RetrieveRequest

```
        var m_etclient = new etAPI.ClientID();
        m_etclient.ID = 123456;
        m_etclient.IDSpecified = true;
        rr.ClientIDs = new etAPI.ClientID[1];
        rr.ClientIDs[0] = m_etclient;
```

Comment: I've added my current code so you can see what I'm doing.  Not using the XML, but the c# webservice library.  It looks like it should be good.  Can you see anything I'm missing?

Comment: your code looks fine, not sure why you still get that error. maybe try remove more attributes, I only have new string[] { "Name", "CategoryID"} and a simple filter like yours and it works for me. Also try setting ClientID for rr request, I have updated my answer for that details. It can cause errors if you are trying to access a businessunit that is not parent.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried both suggestions (limiting the properties, setting client ID) and I still get the same error: Error: The Filter Property 'CategoryID' is not a retrievable property.  Stumped at this point.

Comment: @Mike, I suggest to download Fiddler to track what is sending to SFMC. download and open Fiddler, run your app, in Fiddler's left panel looking for a log of "/Service.asmx", in the right panel, top half is your xml envelope request, click  on "Raw" tab and copy paste your xml request, remove credentials <o:username> <o:password> and <ClientIDs> tag, you can inspect xml response in bottom half panel.  BTW, which endpoint are you pointing to?  s0, s4,s6 or s7?

Comment: I'm using endpoint S1 (https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx).  I'll have to download Fiddler and give that a go so I can post the XML.  Stay tuned!